# UIWebView is null in method called from another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have two viewControllers. `ViewController1` and `ViewController2`.

In `viewController1` I create a `UIWebView` called `webView`.

This is `viewController1.h` :

```
#import "viewController2.h"
@class viewController2

@interface viewController1 : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> 
{

...

}

@property (nonatomic, strong)UIWebView *webView;

- (void)goToPerc:(float)perc;
```

This is `viewController1.m` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ...

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    ...

}

- (void)goToPerc:(float)perc {
    CGPoint scrollToPoint = CGPointMake(0, (int)(self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height * (perc / 100)));
    NSLog(@"%@", webView);
    [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollToPoint animated:YES];
}
```

This is `viewController2.h` :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "viewController1.h"

@interface viewController2 : UIViewController
{
    ...
}
```

This is `viewController2.m` :

```
...

- (void)blaBla
{
    viewController1 *vc1 = [[viewController1 alloc] init];
    float scrollToPerc = 50.0;
    [vc1 goToPerc:scrollToPerc];
    NSLog(@"%@", vc1); // returns viewController1 in log
}
```

The `NSLog(@"%@", webView);` in  `(void)goToPerc:(float)perc` returns null. And the scrolling doesn't work obviously. Why? All the other functions in `viewController1` don't return null on `webView` and `viewDidLoad` on `viewController1` is called so `webView` does exist!

I also tried `self.webView`, no success either.

Comment: Go for protocol and delegate. Search, learn and implement same.

Comment: You have a powerful tool called breakpoint. use it thoroghly in all the methods and check which method gets called and whats wrong.

Comment: I think viewdidload wont get called untill you display your viewcontrollers view the first time.

Comment: viewDidLoad in viewController1 was already called before I call [vc1 goToPerc:scrollToPerc]; in viewController2.

Comment: You should read some articles about view life cycle.

Comment: Did you synthesized the property? if autosynthesized you should access it using _webView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think with this you are creating a new viewcontroller, insead accessing the previous one

```
viewController1 *vc1 = [[viewController1 alloc] init];
    float scrollToPerc = 50.0;
    [vc1 goToPerc:scrollToPerc];
    NSLog(@"%@", vc1);
```

you could try

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourSecondviewcontrollerIdentifier"]; 
 float scrollToPerc = 50.0;
    [vc1 goToPerc:scrollToPerc];
    NSLog(@"%@", vc1);
```

Comment: This lead to the solution. For me the solution was to call the already instantiated VC with a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not pushed your view controller in the navigation so that view could load of latest viewController. Your viewController object is created that is why you are able to access its property or method which are public.

So you can create object of your viewController by using this method in your blabla method:

```
viewController1ViewController *vc1 = [[viewController1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and

then you can write all stuff in this method which you have written in viewDidLoad

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Or if you want to present your viewController then you can use pushViewController of navigationController property of your controller like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:NO];
```

This will invoke your `viewDidLoad`:

I guess it should clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Because you create your webView in code it is only created during viewDidLoad.

When creating viewController1, `view` isn't loaded before any attempt to access the view, so `viewDidLoad` isn't called, so your webView isn't created.

You have many different solutions:

a) add the webView directly in you viewController1.xib file (and make it an IBOutlet)

b) access the `view` right after creating viewController1 (ie: `[vc1 view];`)

c) only call `goToPerc:` after pushing/presenting the viewController